# Autofill date in a column according month based on user input

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to know is it possible to autofill date in a column of particular month, when the month is provided by the user.

For example: I have two sheet (SHEET1 and SHEET2). If I enter the name of month like April in SHEET1, the column A1:A30 in SHEET2 should filled automatically from date 01/04/2020 to 30/04/2020.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub INeedADate()
    Dim mnth As String, StartDate As Date, d As Date
    Dim i As Long
    
    mnth = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    StartDate = DateValue("1 " & mnth & " 2020")
    
    For i = 0 To 35
        d = StartDate + i
        If Month(d) <> Month(StartDate) Then Exit Sub
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = d
    Next i
End Sub
```